# Link to a file inside an HTML email

Tags: html, email, file, hyperlink

I have a file located on a shared network and I want to include a link to this file in my html email which I will send internally using dotmailer or campaign monitor, etc. However, the link won't launch...do you have any ideas on how I can get around this? Thanks

My link looks like:

```
file://location/example.pdf
```

Thanks.

Comment: What e-mail client does it need to work on?

Answer (score 0):

Try with 3 slashes: `file:///location/example.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a-href?

```
<a href='file:///location/example.pdf'> description </a>?
```

Maybe in combination with the servername. And, afaik, 3 slashes with 'file'.

Answer (score -1):

If it is on the internal network, you'd need something like:

```
\\[server name]\pathtofile\file.pdf
```

Comment: I have tried that but when I use Dotailer or Campaign monitor it adds http:// in the front :(

Comment: Does it add http even when you use:
file://[server name]/pathtofile/file.pdf?

Answer (score -1):

You must include the server name.  Try this:

```
//SERVERNAME/SHARE/example.pdf
```

If the server doesn't have a name, you can use the IP address.  In outlook it will show as a valid link.  You could also try:

```
file://SERVERNAME/SHARE/example.pdf
```

Where `SHARE` is the name of the folder on the server.

Comment: I have tried that too but the link doesn't launch from the email :(